# how to check linq comparing date format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datetime

Say I want record of all employees of date "07/03/2013" where format is "MM/dd/yyyy". 
my expression in linq will be :

```
_dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Where(Function(f) f.EmpId = _empId And f.Date="07/03/2013")
```

here how linq manage the date format as "MM/dd/yyyy". OR how to compare "`f.Date`" with MM/dd/yyyy ?

Say,
if i does

```
_dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Where(Function(f) f.EmpId = _empId And f.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")="07/03/2013")
```

It does not allow me. suppose my date will "07/13/2013" then we can consider it matches and sync the format with `"f.Date"` but what about date is under 12 ? In fact by using first expression, m getting march month records, rather July. 
How to figure out this issue?

Comment: Are you doing this with LINQ to SQL? Or LINQ to EF? In either case the `linq` tag is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing string representations of the date/time, which depend on the current system's formatting options. Use a [date literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (must be in 'M/d/yyyy') to create a new `DateTime` object:

```
_dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Where(Function(f) f.EmpId = _empId And f.Date=#3/7/2013#)
```

If it's a variable, say `dte`:

```
_dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Where(Function(f) f.EmpId = _empId And f.Date=dte)
```

Comment: but say my 3/7/2013 is in variable then how should i use literal ? it again will mismatch in format. right ?

Comment: Thanks but still i think linq checking with its own format. edited is not working somehow. any other idea?

Comment: When comparing two `DateTime` instances, the format is irrelevant. It will compare the value of both instances, and return true if they are the same. What makes you think there is a string-based comparison? Is the code compiling? If your `3/7/2013` is in a variable, make sure it is of type `DateTime` and not a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:

```
_dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Where
   (Function(f) f.EmpId = _empId And
                f.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")="07/03/2013")
```

You where passing `Month` first, so it parses March. Change `toString` order so you pass days before and then month. (July)

Comment: well, f.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") does not allowed by Linq. so cant use this